# writing a camera using app on android

Tags: android, eclipse, camera

I'm new to android programming but have tried several ways to use the camera app.

I want a photo to be taken every 5 minutes and sent to my server, but each method I've tried ends up supplying me with an app that gives me the built in camera app that expects me to press the shutter.  I need this automated

The 'wrapper' in Cordova does this.  The example on the android developer pages does this and I have the suspicion as I work through the Android programming book that the camera pp example will do the same.

Comment: Do you have a question?   Other than "please give me the code"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//somewhere in your code call this (Maybe you need to set up a timer):
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall); 

//this should be done before using camera
Camera mCamera; 
private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
boolean qOpened = false;

    try {
        releaseCamera();
        mCamera = Camera.open(id);
        qOpened = (mCamera != null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return qOpened;    
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

   // you need to change this method due to your needs
   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
         //decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap

         FileOutputStream outStream = null;
              try {
                  outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Image.jpg");
                  outStream.write(data);
                  outStream.close();
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                  Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
              } catch (IOException e){
                  Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
              }

   }
};
```